# Message segmentation vs message switching?

Tags: tcp, switching

Is message segmentation and switching the same thing?

Segmentation is when the max transmission unit is smaller than the size of the data packet, so we have to break it up into multiple packets.

Switching is just breaking up the packet to get to a destination, for some reason?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Segmentation (or rather fragmentation)**

Although in some literature you may find the term `segmentation` to refer to the process of dividing an IP packet that is bigger than the `Maximum Transfer Unit` (MTU) of the link,  the correct term is `fragmentation`.

See [@adam86](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/24620/adam86) answer for what segmentation refers to.

**Switching**
Switching is totally different, it refers to the process, performed by devices commonly known as `switch`, although the official term is `mac bridge`, which transfer (unchanged), an Ethernet frame from a LAN to another LAN.
Mac bridges are defined by the IEEE standard 802.1D

In modern Ethernet networking, switching is performed when a switch receives an Ethernet frame on one of its ports and transfers it to another port on which the receiver is attached.

The switch use the destination MAC address present in the Ethernet frame to select the port to send the frame to.

The term "switching" come from the fact the frame is recopied from one port to another one, by opposition with older hubs which send the frame to all ports (except the one on which the frame was received).

Answer (score 1):

TCP breaks up a message into small pieces known as segments. This process is called segmentation. Keep in mind that TCP is a byte stream protocol. It's up to Layer 4 to create chunks not bigger than the Maximum Segment Size which is the largest segment (piece of data) that can be transferred in an IP packet which in turn is limited by MTU that is the maximum size of a packet that can traverse a given physical link.

@JFK The term segmentation is sometime used to refer to the process of dividing an ethernet frame that is bigger than the Maximum Transfer Unit (MTU) of the link

isn't this called fragmentation?

HTH
Adam

Comment: did you read the end of my sentence? "but this is more generally referred as fragmentation."

Comment: I didn't want to offend you by any means. Yes I did. But calling it segmentation is not the right term. It's fragmentation. :-) to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: no offense taken, I agree with you, this is the op that used the term. I'll edit my answer to better reflect that this usage is not quite correct.

Comment: @JFL, actually, fragmentation is part of the IP (layer-3) protocol, not layer-2. Fragmentation happens at layer-3, but layer-2, like ethernet, will just discard oversize frames, not fragment them.

Comment: @RonMaupin, yes you're right of course. Thanks.